# A solution to embed affiliate data (id/logo) into an installer

Tags: installation, setuptools, download

I think about a solution (I guess, server based solution), which inserts affiliate ids/logos into an windows installer (setup.exe, set's up a video converter program, nothing fancy) on the fly.

I see the process like this:

1) User clicks on the link with affiliate ID, link requests server for a download file, system on the fly inserts affiliate's logo and id in to this installer... but I guess this solution is rather a science fiction, cause I can't imagine that this can be done on the fly in seconds.

2) So as the second way of doing this, I see a script/program which automatically creates setup files with affiliate's logos and ID's and stores it on the server, for example, once a day.

Any solutions available on the market of doing this? Or, maybe, this can be achieved with simple HEX editing?